# “Insecure Login Blocked: You can’t get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://"

Tags: r

I am getting the error message:

> Insecure Login Blocked: You can’t get an access token or log in to
>   this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://

Command used in Rstudio:

```
appID <- "My app ID"
appSecret <- "My app secret"
fb_oauth <- fbOAuth(app_id=appID, app_secret=appSecret, extended_permissions = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

appID <- "My app ID"
appSecret <- "My app secret"
fb_oauth <- fbOAuth(app_id=appID, app_secret=appSecret, extended_permissions = TRUE)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).